Strange growth on founation
I was on vacation for about 10 days, and when I went water the lawn today, I saw this beauty.  It is about 12" wide.
Fungus?  Other?  Ignore?  Worry?
[]
[]

It's a mushroom. You can ignore it or remove it. They will not damage the foundation.

Thanks!  I was going to say it looked like a slice of pizza... ;)

Unless it's attacking the wood of your house (dry rot or similar), it's harmless.
